# Picasso never calling completion handler while trying to load an image on Android

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, picasso

I am trying to load an image:

```
   Picasso.with(SelectActivity.this).load(picture).into(new Target() {
        @Override
        public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
            bmp = bitmap;
            findViewById(R.id.facebookButton).setEnabled(true);
            continueToEditing();
        }

        @Override
        public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
            findViewById(R.id.facebookButton).setEnabled(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

        }
    });
```

`picture` is a valid string to a reachable, valid JPEG image. I've got everything inside a try/catch block and I've got breakpoints on `onBitmapLoaded`, `onBitmapFailed`, and try/catch's catch block.

However, none of this is called. There is also nothing in logcat related to this, too. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Faced similar issue. Never solved it. I ended up writing my custom image loader from here : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache.html

Comment: It's the classic problem that Picasso only holds weak references to Targets. You need to hold on to your Target to keep it around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try keeping a **strong** reference to the Target object as a class variable and give it a try.

E.g.

```
Target target;// Class variable
//Now define this on your onCreate method
target = new Target() {
    @Override
    public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
        bmp = bitmap;
        findViewById(R.id.facebookButton).setEnabled(true);
        continueToEditing();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
        findViewById(R.id.facebookButton).setEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

    }
});
//Now set the target on the Piccaso load LOC
Picasso.with(SelectActivity.this).load(picture).into(target);
```